# Restricting number of occurrences of an element based on its attribute value in XSD possible?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I am working on the schema for an XML-based configuration file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Configuration">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Services">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <!--
                Each service represents a specific web service. During the validation of the XML configuration
                against the schema an additional check for multiple occurrences of the same service must take place to ensure proper configuration.

                If support for more services is added increase maxOccurs accordingly. Currently supported are
                  * Service1
                  * Service2
                  * Service3
              -->
              <xs:element maxOccurs="3" name="Service">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="ConnectionStatusUsedFor">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="Table" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                        <xs:attribute name="Column" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                        <xs:attribute name="Row" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="required" />
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <!--
                      Used only by service of type DeviceService
                    -->
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="VersionInfo">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="Application" type="xs:string" default="Ultimate Software" />
                          <xs:element name="OS" type="xs:string" default="Debian 9" />
                          <xs:element name="Manufacturer" type="xs:string" default="Some company" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                  <xs:attribute name="port" type="xs:unsignedShort" use="required" />
                  <!--
                    The URI is added as a path to the address where the respective service is made available for the
                    clients to connect to. The format is

                    http://127.0.0.1:[port]/[uri]

                    with [port] being the value taken from the port-attribute
                  -->
                  <xs:attribute name="uri" use="required">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:enumeration value="Service1.soap"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="Service2.soap"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="Service3.soap"/>
                      </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                  </xs:attribute>
                  <xs:attribute name="Timeout" type="xs:duration" use="required" />
                  <!--
                    The version of a service (see operation GetServiceVersion) defines which operations the service supports.
                    The limited range here is defined as the smallest and largest version number available among all
                    services. This also means that some services do not support a given higher version so additional
                    service-specific check must take place during the validation of the XML configuration against the
                    schema
                  -->
                  <xs:attribute name="version" use="required">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                      <xs:restriction base="xs:unsignedByte">
                        <xs:minInclusive value="0" />
                        <xs:maxInclusive value="5" />
                      </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                  </xs:attribute>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>

        <!-- rest of configuration -->

      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Here is an example of the XML document that is to be validated against the XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Configuration>
  <Services>
    <!--
    Service:
      port    The port that we listen to for incomming data from a client
      uri     The path for the client to access the respective web service

      Note that all web services are hosted on localhost, which (given a
      port and uri) always results in http://127.0.0.1:<port>/<uri> as the
      service end point for the client to connect to

      version The version of the web service. Based on it's value (an integer)
    -->
    <Service port="8081" uri="HelloWorldService1.soap" Timeout="PT30S" version="5"/>
    <Service port="8085" uri="HelloWorldService2.soap" Timeout="PT30S" version="0"/>
    <Service port="8082" uri="HelloWorldService3.soap" Timeout="PT30S" version="1">
      <VersionInfo>
        <Application>My Software</Application>
        <OS>Debian 9</OS>
        <Manufacturer>Hello World</Manufacturer>
      </VersionInfo>
    </Service>
  </Services>

  <!-- rest of configuration -->

</Configuration>
```

Now the problem is that I would like to keep the `Service` element as a common element for every service that is added while at the same time restrict the instances to a single one **based on the URI**. For example the following should not be possible (it is with the current XSD):

```
<Service port="8082" uri="HelloWorldService3.soap" Timeout="PT30S" version="0">
<Service port="8085" uri="HelloWorldService3.soap" Timeout="PT30S" version="1">
```

The reason: the `uri` attribute has the same value for both `Service` elements. The other attributes can (and it makes perfect sense) be the same.

Is this possible? I will probably at some point move to separate element per service type since some will include configuration service elements that are not used within the context of others.

Comment: Your question title talks of restricting the number of occurrences of an element based on its attribute value. You haven't mentioned any attribute values in your explanation, so I'm not at all clear what the rule is that you want to impose. Generally, this kind of rule requires XSD 1.1, but it would be nice to know what exactly the rule is before saying that definitively.

Comment: @MichaelKay Will add it. It is the `uri`'s value however now I see that the example has every attribute the same hence it is really confusing. I did mention that the URI is the restriction rule before the example.

Comment: I think you are simply saying that every `Service` within a `Services` must have a distinct `@uri` value, and that's what `xs:unique` is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add a `unique` constraint that selects the `Service` element / `uri` attribute pair, like:

```
 <xs:element name="Services">
      <xs:unique name="unique-serviceUri">
        <xs:selector xpath="Service"/>
        <xs:field xpath="@uri"/>
      </xs:unique>
    [...]
```

Of course, regarding your question, this would allow to restrict to exactly one element with the given attribute value, not an arbitrary number of them.

Comment: I don't understand the last part "not an arbitrary number of them". I am looking for uniqueness regarding the `uri` so having multiple number of `Service` elements with the same `uri` is not what I am looking for.

Comment: @rbaleksandar that's exactly what my answer is doing; the mention was to the question you posted in the title, in which you ask for generically 'restricting' (ie upper/lower bounds), not for uniqueness.